# SQL Server Query Date convert Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to add where condition in my query like  2012-10-05 00:29:06.338 <= Today'sdatetime however I am getting the issue.

Please help me to sort out this issue.

My query is given below :

```
Select * from table1
where 
CONVERT(varchar(12),'2012-10-05 00:29:06.338', 106) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(12),'2012-10-05 00:29:06.338', 108) <= CONVERT(varchar(12), GETDATE(),106) + ' 23:59:00.000'
```

Comment: Would help if you let us know the issue or output you're getting

Comment: I m getting error < then syntax:(

Comment: which DBMS are you using?
Can you edit your post and copy/paste the error into it

Comment: SQL server 2008 R2 and Error is incorrect suntax near <

Comment: Also, 2012-10-05 00:29:06.338 this value is saved in col1 in table1 so query would be Select * from table1
where 
CONVERT(varchar(12),col1, 106) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(12),col1, 108) <= CONVERT(varchar(12), GETDATE(),106) + ' 23:59:00.000'

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to evaluate a string as a date:

```
Select '8'
where 
CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(varchar,Col1, 101)) 
+ ' ' + CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(varchar,Col1,108)) 
<= CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(),101))+' ' + CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(varchar,'23:59:00.000', 108))
```

Comment: I am trying to use ur query : Select CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(varchar,'2012-10-05', 101)) + ' ' + CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(varchar,'00:29:06.338',108)) <= CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(),101))+' ' + CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(varchar,'23:59:00.000', 108))

Comment: Check the edit, it works fine in SSMS. You are not evaluating anything in your table1. That is how you compare dates and times.

Comment: I just want to display all the records from table wherein col1 <= Today'sDateTime. Eg Col1 value like this 2012-10-05 00:29:06.338 is saved in table1. Col1 datatype is Datetime. so Query would be Select * from table1 where CONVERT(varchar(12),col1, 106) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(12),col1, 108) <= CONVERT(varchar(12), GETDATE(),106) + ' 23:59:00.000' . Please advice now.

Comment: Please read my comment and would appreciate if u reply on the same.

Comment: SELECT ID AS 'ID', FROMADDRESS AS 'FROM',  SUBJECTLINE AS 'SUBJECT', MESSAGEBODY AS 'MESSAGEBODY', DATECREATED AS 'CREATED',DATEPROCESSED AS 'PROCESSED',SENDAFTER AS 'SENDAFTER',ISNULL(REFERENCE,'') AS 'REFERENCE',NORETRIES AS 'RETRIES',ISERROR AS 'ISERROR',
          ISHTML AS 'HTML'
 FROM EMailTABLE WITH (READPAST)
 WHERE ( DATEPROCESSED IS NOT NULL ) 
 AND ISERROR = 0
  AND 
    CONVERT(varchar(12), SENDAFTER, 106) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(12), SENDAFTER, 108) <= CONVERT(varchar(12), GETDATE(),106) + ' 23:59:00.000'
ORDER BY ID, DATECREATED DESC

Comment: Please select an answer if we helped.

Comment: no this answer is not helping me out. As I just want to give condition  as SendAfterdate should be <= current datetime. Wherein SendAfterdate datatype is Date in table and value is saved in this format 2012-10-05 00:29:06.338.

Comment: When I replace AND CONVERT(varchar(12), SENDAFTER, 106) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(12), SENDAFTER, 108) <= CONVERT(varchar(12), GETDATE(),106) + ' 23:59:00.000                                         with    SENDAFTER <= GETDATE() in above query it gives 30 mins to run the query which is really very bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do date comparisons by converting both values to a varchar.  You need to convert the values to datetime and compare.

If you have a column in your database named `col1` that is a datetime, you can compare this directly to `GETDATE()`.

For example: 
`select * from table1 where col1 > GETDATE()`

If you really need to compare a date with a string you can explicitly convert to datetime:

```
Select * 
from table1
where CONVERT(DATETIME,'2012-10-05 00:29:06.338') <= GETDATE()
```

OR you can let SQL Server implicitly do the conversion for you:

```
Select * 
from table1
where '2012-10-05 00:29:06.338' <= GETDATE()
```

Comment: This condition really taking long time to run query :(

Comment: Please check my query and reply me asap.

Comment: SELECT ID AS 'ID', FROMADDRESS AS 'FROM', SUBJECTLINE AS 'SUBJECT', MESSAGEBODY AS 'MESSAGEBODY', DATECREATED AS 'CREATED',DATEPROCESSED AS 'PROCESSED',SENDAFTER AS 'SENDAFTER',ISNULL(REFERENCE,'') AS 'REFERENCE',NORETRIES AS 'RETRIES',ISERROR AS 'ISERROR', ISHTML AS 'HTML' FROM EMailTABLE WITH (READPAST) WHERE ( DATEPROCESSED IS NOT NULL ) AND ISERROR = 0 AND CONVERT(varchar(12), SENDAFTER, 106) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(12), SENDAFTER, 108) <= CONVERT(varchar(12), GETDATE(),106) + ' 23:59:00.000' ORDER BY ID, DATECREATED DESC –